# Launch Modal On Route - Form Validation - [Laravel]

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a login and registration page on a modal when you click the 'Sign Up' or 'Login Button'. Although I can't do validation on it because it opens as a modal.

Is there a way where I can make a route like 'login' and If there are any errors to load that route and AUTOMATICALLY load the register/login modal, which from there I can display all my validation errors.

Example. (I know this doesn't work)

```
Route::get('/logintest', function(){
  $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    });
})->name('login.test');


  <a data-rel="loginModal" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-lock"></I> 
Login                  
                      </a>
```

Comment: Include the script in your view template for that route

Comment: use redirect where error return

Comment: remove js code from `route` add those line in your view when `window.load`

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX and handle response error. You don't have to refresh page with errors and show modal.